# It wont let me examine the crime scene or talk to Jorleif for assistance

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ive tried examining the crime scene but nothing happens and when i talk to jorleif there is no option to get assistance. Is it because i picked the lock? I also took the strange element is that why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the trail of blood going to a certain house from the crime scene? I won't say anymore to prevent spoilers.